# update data in chart (dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dojo, dojox.charting

In my code below, the data is updated but the chart is not redrawn in the same position. What is the problem in my code?

(more information in firebug if you want - json is updated when the las dropdown is changed - only the category designer have data)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.query(".estatistica").onchange(function() {
        dojo.xhrPost({
            url: "drop2.php",
            handleAs: "json",
            postData: "data=" + $(this).val(),
            preventCache: true,
            load: function(json) {
                $msgs = [];

                for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                    $msgs.push(parseFloat(json[i]["valor" + i]));
                }
                var chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D('chart1');
                chart1.addPlot("default", {
                    type: "StackedAreas",
                    markers: true,
                    tension: "S",
                    lines: true,
                    areas: true,
                    labelOffset: 0,

                });
                chart1.addAxis('x');
                chart1.addAxis('y', {
                    vertical: true,
                    max: 80000
                });

                chart1.addSeries('January Visits', $msgs, {
                    stroke: 'red',
                    fill: 'pink'
                });


                chart1.updateSeries("January Visits", $msgs);
                chart1.render();


            var stackedAreaLegend = new dojox.charting.widget.SelectableLegend({
                chart: chart1
            }, "legend1");

            stackedAreaLegend.refresh();

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: i need to draw a chart before the update. solved

Comment: People don't often respond to "fix my code" posts and instead require a bit more work from the asker to identify _what_ doesn't work specifically and to provide some critical context.

Comment: Please make an answer if you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, render your chart, then do any updates.  Just switch these two lines, as shown:

```
            chart1.render();
            chart1.updateSeries("January Visits", $msgs);
```